# Open Windows 7's Network Connections control panel applet as different user

Tags: windows-7, networking, permissions, control-panel, runas

I'm trying to change network settings without constantly switching to my admin account (which is *not* `Administrator`). I have a weird corporate admin account - `local-timmmm`.

Usually to install apps and so on, I have to shift-right-click them, select `Run as different user` and run them as `local-timmmm`. `Run as Administrator` *does not work*.

Ok so on to the question, how can I access the "Network Connections" control panel applet as `local-timmmm` without switching account? These are some of the things that I've tried that ***do not work***:

1. Start a `cmd.exe` as `local-timmmm` and run `ncpa.cpl`. It runs, but says I have no permission still.
2. Browse to `c:\Windows\System32\ncpa.cpl`, shift-right-click it. There is a `Run as Administrator` option but no `Run as different user`.
3. Using `mmc.exe` - this works for the Device Manager, but there doesn't seem to be any way to access any other control panel things from it.
4. Running explorer as `local-timmmm` and browsing to the Network Connections page. Still no permissions.

I'm starting to suspect this is impossible.

Comment: What is it specifically you need to get at/change on the network configuration page? Many/Most/All of the settings in there can be set via command-line commands.

Comment: It might be blocked by the domain administrator via group policy. It might be blocked by system due to license limitation that does not allow two users to actively use the same system at the same time. Check event log what is being reported when you get access denied message.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Yeah I know I am just trying to find if there is a nice easy GUI way. At the moment I'm trying to set the network adapter route metrics.

Comment: @mnmnc But it works if I actually switch user to `local-timmmm`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start a program with another user using "runas". Bear in mind that it expects an executable (that's why the control.exe is mentioned explicitly).

> runas /user:username "control ncpa.cpl"